# Does inequality hold under limit in holomorphic function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

If i have $|f(z)|\leq|f(z^n)|$ in the unit disk, and $f$ is holomorphic, does it follow that 
$|f(z)|\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f(z^n)|=|f(0)|$?

Comment: What do you think? Does $z^n \to 0$ imply $f(z^n) \to f(0)$?

Comment: Well yes, but do I know that the inequality holds at the limit $f(0)$ if it holds everywhere else? I suppose that follows from the function being holomorphic? @Martin R

Comment: This has nothing to do with holomorphy. $f(z^n) \to f(0)$ because $f$ is *continuous.* And $|f(z)|\leq|f(z^n)|$ for all $n$ implies $\lim |f(z)|\leq \lim |f(z^n)|$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1589689/42969.

Comment: @Martin R Thanks that makes sense!

Comment: If the function is supposed to be holomorphic, not only do we have this (as @MartinR noted that depends only on the continuity of the function): we also have that $f$ is constant, from the maximum modulus principle, as you can see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566798/if-f-is-an-entire-function-satisfying-fz-leq-fz2-for-all-z-in-bbb/3566811#3566811